# Логирование подготовленного запроса в groovy

Tags: java, sql, groovy

Мне требуется логировать подготовленные запросы в groovy

Для предотвращения sql-инъекций и возможности автоподстановки кавычек для строковых значений(это важно) я использую следующую конструкцию:

```
String name = "Петя"
Integer status = 1    
def query = 'UPDATE my_tbl SET status=? WHERE name=?';
sql.execute (query, [status, name])
```

Как я могу получить подготовленный запрос с подставленными параметрами? Может есть другие пути решения этой проблемы?

Comment: А почему бы просто не залогировать? Типа такого: Выполнение запроса: 'UPDATE my_tbl SET status=? WHERE name=?' с параметрами: status=1, name=Петя

Comment: @ezhov_da Можно и так, но groovy выполняет интересную магию под капотом, например, строковым значениям добавляет кавычки, дату преобразует в соответствующий формат, и хотелось бы в идеале видеть результат этих преобразований в логах.

Comment: Я на 90% процентов уверен, что это делает не groovy, а обычный PreparedStatment, который groovy и оборачивает в приведенном примере, а оттуда достать сформированный запрос достаточно проблематично(нет открытого API)

Comment: @ezhov_da Тогда да, ваш вариант это видимо выход. Или, возможно, есть какой-нибудь вариант через рефлекшн это сделать?

Comment: Думаю тогда придется завязываться на конкретные драйвера к БД.